# php ceil function rounding up not working properly for particular series

Tags: php

This is the function I have

```
function trimprice($currency, $x=5, $sf=2) {
    $scale = pow(10,$sf);
    return number_format(round(ceil($currency*$scale / $x), $sf) * $x / $scale, $sf);
}
```

If I give input

This is the actual result I expect

1. 2.5 => 2.50
2. 1.62 => 1.65

But If I have 1.1 it show 1.15 instead of 1.10 and for 2.2 it shows 2.25 instead of 2.20

Why this is happening in ceil function?

Comment: Show rules of your "rounding". What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

It's because floating point values are inherently inaccurate. Try

```
var_export(1.1);
```

And see what it prints. Searching for "floating point accuracy" should give
you plenty of information about it.

Hopefully you can live with this, but if you can't then use rationals instead.